# React Redux thunk - render app after dispatches finishes

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, redux, redux-thunk

My app uses React, Redux and Thunk. 
**Before** my app renders I wish to dispatch some data to the store.

How can I make sure the `ReactDOM.render()` is run **after** all dispatches has finished?
See my code below

index.js

```
const setInitialStore = () => {
  return dispatch => Promise.all([
    dispatch(startSubscribeUser()),
    dispatch(startSubscribeNotes()),
  ]).then(() => {
    console.log('initialLoad DONE')
    return Promise.resolve(true)
  })
}

store.dispatch(setInitialStore()).then(()=>{
  console.log('Render App')
  ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById('app'))
})
```

Actions

```
export const setUser = (user) => ({
  type: SET_USER,
  user
})
export const startSubscribeUser = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const uid = getState().auth.id

    database.ref(`users/${uid}`)
    .on('value', (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.val()
      const user = {
        ...data
      }
      console.log('user.on()')
      dispatch(setUser(user))
    })
  }
}

export const setNote = (note) => ({
  type: SET_NOTE,
  note
})
export const startSubscribeNotes = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    database.ref('notes')
    .on('value', (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.val()
      const note = {
        ...data
      }
      console.log('note.on()')
      dispatch(setNote(note))
    })
  }
}
```

My log shows

```
"initialLoad DONE"
"Render App"
...
"user.on()"
"note.on()"
```

What I expect is for `user.on()` and `note.on()` to be logged before `initialLoad DONE` and `Render App`

Many thanks! /K

Comment: Well actually I don't see why your code wouldn't work.

Comment: Maybe you can make a HOC with dispatch, render the child component with the condition of find required data in your store.

Comment: Thanks @EmmanuelMericdeBellefon ! Yes I expected the code to work too, but the logging indicates that my actions are not completed before render. :/ I have added log messages to my post.

Comment: Ok I think I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is because `startSubscribeUser` and `startSubscribeNotes` *don't return a function returning a promise*.

Then, what happens in this case, is that the `database.ref` is not *waited* to be completed before executing what's in the next then.

I don't know exactly what that `database` variable is, but this should work :

```
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    database.ref(`users/${uid}`)
    .on('value', (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.val()
      const user = {
        ...data
      }
      console.log('user.on()')
      dispatch(setUser(user))
      resolve()
    })
  })
```